# Using mhchem with gfsneohellenic gives a weird looking arrow

Tags: mhchem, gfsneohellenic

When using `mhchem` package with `gfsneohellenic` font the resulting arrow in chemical reactions is weird. Is there anyway to resolve this?
[image]

[image]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{gfsneohellenicot}
\usepackage{mhchem}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}%
\ce{H2 + 1/2O2 -> H2O} 
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It isn't just `mhchem` `\xrightarrow{test}` from `amsmath` also looks bad.

Comment: @daleif Also `\longrightarrow`, for simplicity.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default, `mhchem`'s arrows are composed by characters from current math font. This requires the corresponding glyphs being able to pieced together, and `gfsneohellenicot` seems to be not capable to do this. Extendable math arrows like `\xleftarrow` and `\xrightarrow` will give similar broken output. (In fact, `mhchem` re-used `\xrightarrow`'s code, from the `amsmath`package.)

For `mhchem`, you can config it to draw the arrow using `tikz`. For example,

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{gfsneohellenicot}
\usepackage[version=4, arrows=pgf{To[length=3pt]}{.15ex}]{mhchem}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \ce{H2 + 1/2O2 -> H2O}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

- The full document of package option `pgf={<arrow tip>}{<line width>}` can be found in [documentation of `mhchem`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mhchem/mhchem.pdf), subsection "Arrows" (page 18 for v4.08).
- You can also use things like `\ce{->}` to substitute broken extendable arrow commands, as well.

Comment: This arrow looks good with the font!